# WSO2 identity server email as username

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are currently evaluating the WSO2 Identity server. We want to use email address as an username. By default the username is 30 characters, it is not long enough. And it must support both . and @ in the username. Is there an way to configure this? The user store is a JDBC(Mysql) one.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes..  you can do it..

Step1. Open carbon.xml in IS_HOME/repository/conf  and uncomment

`<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>`

Step2. Open user-mgt.xml in IS_HOME/repository/conf  and uncomment  JDBC configurations

`org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager`

And

Comment default LDAP user store manager configurations.

`org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager`

Step3. Please add following property under the `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager` configurations.

`<Property name="UsernameWithEmailJavaScriptRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9@._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>`

Using above property, you can change the pattern of your email address...  By default it must be more than 3 characters and less then 30,  But you can configure it as you wish..

Step4. Restart the server

You can find more details on using email username from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2014/10/07/email-username-with-identity-server/). This article clearly explain all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official doc on this: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Email+Authentication

By default '@' is interpreted as a special character to build full qualified usernames for multi-tenant environments.  So you'll need to configure the server to interpret otherwise.