# Mutable username in wso2is

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

My requirement is to authenticate users by email, but also allow a user to change his/her email later.

To authenticate users by email I'm using email as username as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157567/wso2-identity-server-email-as-username). However I can not figure out how to allow changing the user's email, as usernames are immutable.

Is there any way to allow mutable usernames?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JDBC user store that is shipped with Carbon products. It is not possible to change the user name...  Say you are creating a user with "foo@bar" and This name is saved as user name in the tables. And you can not change this name using a API or UI.  But if your user store is a LDAP or any other custom user store, You have freedom to use the attribute for user name...  And it can be changed user user profiles..