# WSO2 identity server email or pseudo as username

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

This is quite the same question as [WSO2 identity server email as username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157567/wso2-identity-server-email-as-username) but we want to have both choice to provide username as email address or user's name (pseudo without @).

I understand the problem with the tenant fully qualified name using @ but can't we change the @ character for the tenant fully qualified ?

Is it possible to use both email address or user's name as username and if so can you provide the configuration, I cannot make it work following https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username

I edited my question to test both Rajjaz Mohammed and Pradeepa Wickramasinghe answers :

I commented `<Property name="UsernameJavascriptRegEx">`
When I add a user without @ I get :

`Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Username jacques.martin is not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format, ^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1405)`

If I remove this tag `<Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">` I get the following error :

`TID: [1] [] [2016-11-22 13:16:50,409] admin@test.com@mytenant.com [1] [IS]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.util.Utils} -  Unable to retrieve the claim for user : jacques.martin@mytenant.com
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: UserNotFound: User jacques.martin@mytenant.comdoes not exist in: PRIMARY
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:168)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:697)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.util.Utils.getClaimFromUserStoreManager(Utils.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.util.Utils.getEmailAddressForUser(Utils.java:226)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.mail.AbstractEmailSendingModule.getNotificationAddress(AbstractEmailSendingModule.java:53)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.RecoveryProcessor.notifyWithEmail(RecoveryProcessor.java:541)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.services.UserInformationRecoveryService.registerUser(UserInformationRecoveryService.java:890)`

Same error with Pradeepa Wickramasinghe's answer.

My java code is as follow :

`userInformationRecoveryClient.registerUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), claims, "default", tenant );`

In claims I have correctly set http://wwso2.org/claims/email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ,is it possible to used user name as both **email** or **username**. For that you need to follow the steps below,

1. Enable the email user name by **uncomment** in [IS_HOME]/repository/conf/carbon.xml file as below,

`<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>`

2. Add new property in to the [IS_HOME]/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml file as below,

`<Property name="UsernameWithEmailJavaScriptRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9@._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>`

3. Changed the "UsernameJavaRegEx" and "UsernameJavaScriptRegEx" in [IS_HOME]/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml file as below,

`<Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9@._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>`

```
<Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
```

You can found more details [here](https://workaroundz.blogspot.com/2017/01/authenticate-user-by-usernameoremail.html).

Comment: Thank for your answer but this is not working when I add a user to a tenant. Question edited with stacktrace

Comment: I read your update but you are using different regex instead of I added above. Your issue happen when you are using this regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$". Please verify your setup with my configuration.

Comment: I test both solution, the same error happend with your answer too, might be a bug. Maybe it works without account confirmation ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this line code

```
<Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$</Property>
```

Insted of using this line

```
<Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$</Property>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but this is not working when add user to a tenant. Question edited with full trace

Answer (score 0):

Because we call AD for our Identity Store, we found that in addition to setting

`<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>`

in `carbon.xml`, we also need to change `UserNameSearchFilter` to search both parts of AD

`<Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp; (objectClass=person)(|(userPrincipalName=?)(sAMAccountName=?)))</Property>`

in `user-mgt.xml`