# How to use both username and mail in authentication Wso2 Identity Server using JDBCUserStore primary userstore

Tags: authentication, jdbc, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure both username and mail as authentication params. So user can login with either username or mail. I can achieve this in **ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager** by replacing following configuration

`<Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(|(mail=?)(uid=?)))</Property>`.

But in JDBCUserStoreManager. I am not able to find any configuration for it. Need help on this

Thanks

Comment: You can found answer here [1].I answered previously.
[1] http://stackoverflow.com/a/40741473

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 identity server email or pseudo as username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718328/wso2-identity-server-email-or-pseudo-as-username)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the email address as the username you have to uncomment the `<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>` config in the **carbon.xml** file.

Adding this will enable the users to be authenticate with their email address. But this will not block username users from registering and login. But you will have to use the fully qualified usernames hereafter.
Eg. `admin@carbon.super` `john@gmail.com@tenant.com`

Default user management configs won't let you use the `@` while registering the user. Therefore, please change the user-mgt.xml file's regex files adding `@` symbol.
Eg. `a-zA-Z0-9@`